# Jetty custom error pages when running as embedded server

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

How do you override the default error pages (suffixed with "Powered by Jetty") when running Jetty as an embedded server?

i.e.

```
Server server = new Server(8080);
server.setHandler(new Handler());

/* configure custom error pages? */

server.start();
server.join();
```

Comment: What version of Jetty (be specific, as the answer is jetty version specific)? Are you just wanting to turn off the "Powered by Jetty?" or something entirely new?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Jetty is coming along with Jenkins. Yes, i am happy by just hiding the version details from the page.

Answer (score 11):

This should solve your problem.

```
    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    context.setContextPath("/*");

    Server jettyServer = new Server(8080);
    jettyServer.setHandler(context);

    ErrorPageErrorHandler errorHandler = new ErrorPageErrorHandler();
    errorHandler.addErrorPage(404, "/missing.html");
    context.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);
```

Comment: Here is the documentation for 9.4.v20161208 which is quite recent one: http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/9.4.0.v20161208/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/servlet/ErrorPageErrorHandler.html